# AJAX call from local HTML file in WebvView

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, android-webview

I'm struggling to get a simple AJAX call working from a local HTML file loaded into a WebView.

My jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
}).done(function(data) {
    // some stuff here to go through data
});
```

And my webview settings:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

I had tried with JSONP but I was getting a parse error, saying the callback was not called (This would work fine on my PC when loaded from a local file, inside Chrome - the callback was definitely working, but Android couldn't figure it out?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in your server script?
In `php` set this header before response:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Noting special has to be set in WebView.
`Opera` usually sends `options` request before `get` or `post`, so this `options` request fails if there is no above header entry, but that's how it works in desktop browser.

Comment: I have set this in the server side PHP script, but it doesn't seem to be working... If I load the file in question from the server itself, the header is there, but locally, the header request is not there.. odd :/

Comment: This is frustrating. If I navigate to the server script that I'm targetting with AJAX, I can see "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" is set. Yet, when I load the HTML file into Chrome on the PC (not through WAMP, just literally opening the file) the AJAX call fails, saying "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." and when I inspect the network call to the server script (on localhost) no Access header is shown!?

Comment: Also try javascript `XMLHttpRequest` if you are not sure for jQuery. Add `Content-Type` request header. Watch for cache, android has bad habit to not update `js` file if `html` file is not changed, so make some dummy change.

Comment: Where should I set the content-type and what should it be?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that chrome can report false `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` when some other error is present.

Comment: If you use `XMLHttpRequest` from javascript then call `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`

Comment: How do I use XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: I used "curl -i http://localhost:81/script.php" to check the headers, and it is not seeing the headers I set. I then tried it in POSTman (Chrome addon) and that shows the new headers....

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem when I put wrong script URL, else everything works perfectly. Can you check your URL in browser? Just type it in address bar.